# Glade + PyGTK Change Button Font Size

Tags: python, pygtk

I am developing Ubuntu app using the Unity tools (PyGTK + Python). I can change label font-size with no problem, but I cannot find same thing for button. How can I change button font-size?

The purpose of this is, i am developing an on-screen keypad, so the numerical text needs to be bigger so that it is easier to be seen.

Comment: I am looking the way to do this with Glade if possible, without having to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button contains a label, which you can access with `get_child()` and related functions. You can change the label's font size using the normal method.

Comment: So in glade..how to i do this without having to dive into the source code?

Comment: In glade, it's needlessly complicated. Click "Add custom button content" in your button properties and add your own label.

Comment: PS. How are you going to develop an app without touching any source code?!

Comment: I want to minimalize editing the controls in the source code.